# Recursion in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression

The `select * from MyTable` gives the following result,
[image]

Now I would like to get ids of all childs if I pass the id of 'Chest'.

For example, if I pass id of 'ChestOne', I would like to get the following table

[image]

I tried the following, but could not get the result

```
;WITH Temp_CTE AS
(
SELECT 
     id
    ,name
    ,parent_id
FROM dbo.MyTable
WHERE id = '12D390AE-FF28-4D50-B3A2-A6CC4E6E02A9'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 
     CS.id
    ,CS.name
    ,CS.parent_id
FROM dbo.MyTable CS
INNER JOIN Temp_CTE ON CS.id =  Temp_CTE.parent_id

)
SELECT * FROM Temp_CTE
```

How can I do it in SQL Server 2008 ?

Comment: Try to change your join around. `INNER JOIN Temp_CTE ON CS.parent_id =  Temp_CTE.id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @MyTable table 
(
  id char(2),
  name varchar(10),
  parent_id char(2)
)  

insert into @MyTable values
('54', 'Chest Two', '12'),
('CD', 'InCOne', '6D'),
('6D', 'ChestOne', '12'),
('12', 'Chest', '00')

;WITH Temp_CTE AS
(
SELECT 
     id
    ,name
    ,parent_id
FROM @MyTable
WHERE id = '6D'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 
     CS.id
    ,CS.name
    ,CS.parent_id
FROM @MyTable CS
INNER JOIN Temp_CTE ON CS.parent_id =  Temp_CTE.id

)
SELECT * FROM Temp_CTE
```

Result:

```
id   name       parent_id
---- ---------- ---------
6D   ChestOne   12
CD   InCOne     6D
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be:

```
;WITH Temp_CTE AS
(
SELECT 
     id
    ,name
    ,parent_id
FROM dbo.MyTable
WHERE id = '12D390AE-FF28-4D50-B3A2-A6CC4E6E02A9'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 
     CS.id
    ,CS.name
    ,CS.parent_id
FROM dbo.MyTable CS
INNER JOIN Temp_CTE ON CS.parent_id =  Temp_CTE.id

)
SELECT * FROM Temp_CTE
```